# Почему в цикле for можно объявлять переменную счетчик без let и var

Tags: javascript

Недавно начал учить js и в отличии от python переменные создаются ключевыми словами, но по привычке вместо let i написал просто i и все работало. Я проверил доступна ли переменная i вне цикла и оказалось, что да. Правильно ли я понял, что если не писать ключевое слово var или let в цикле for(я имею ввиду переменную счетчик), то js сам как бы подставит var? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Если не указывать никакой var/let/const, то по умолчанию переменная становится глобальной и помещается в объект window

Comment: В строгом режиме (`'use strict'`) объявлять переменные без var/let/const запрещено. Если у вас работает, значит вы не включили строгий режим в своём коде

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Если не указывать никакой `var`/`let`/`const`, то по умолчанию переменная становится глобальной и помещается в объект `window` – [@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1405155/#comment2497843_1405155)

```js
for(varName = 0; varName < 10; varName++) {
  document.body.innerText += varName+', ';
}

console.info(window.varName);
```

Comment: Хм.. А почему `window.varName` возвращает `10`? 

Comment: Потому что цикл `for` завершается тогда, когда выражение `varName < 10` станет ложным, а оно станет ложным только когда значение `varName` достигнет значения `10`

Comment: @andreymal, точно, пора отдыхать..